# Need to reset html content on resize

Tags: html, jquery

I have a simple toggle that I have set up to display content differently based on screen width.  However, there is one aspect that I can't get to work.  If the screen size goes less than the desired 600px width it changes to the correct content, but when the screen width is then increased it doesn't go back to the original default content, only the default css (based on the `@media` query).  I am thinking I need to set the original in a variable and then call it again?

Can you please help me with what the missing piece of this puzzle is?

```
$(function() {
    function breadcrumbAdjustment(){
        var screenWidth = $(window).width();
        var originalBreadcrumb = $('.breadcrumbs').clone();
        
        if (screenWidth <= 600) {
            $('.breadcrumbs').html('<li class="sidebar-toggle">mobile toggle goes here</li>');

            $('.sidebar-toggle').on('click', function() {
                $('#sidebar').fadeToggle("fast");
                $('.sidebar-toggle').toggleClass('open');
            });

        }
         
        
        else {
            $('.breadcrumbs').replaceWith(originalBreadcrumb);
        }
    };
    
    $(window).resize(breadcrumbAdjustment);
});
```

Comment: `originalBreadcrumb` will be the new breadcrumb if the user doesn't stop resizing at exactly 600px. Otherwise, it clones the new element. You should be able to do 99% of this with CSS.

Comment: @HereticMonkey - can you please elaborate you solution as an answer?

Comment: Something like `@media (max-width: 600px) { .sidebar-toggle { display: block; } } .sidebar-toggle { display: none; }` would do what your edited snippet would do.

Comment: @HereticMonkey - Unfortunately this doesn't achieve the goal.  The content in the `<div class="breadcrumbs">` that needs to be changed based on screen size. On mobile the content actually becomes a toggle and controls another `<div>`  I will add more of my code to the question for better context. The default breadcrumb for desktop is text and I need that to return from the toggle to the original text when the screen size is increased again.

Comment: I don't see why the code I provided in my last comment wouldn't suffice. You could have the click event handler in there on document ready. Since the toggle would be invisible at larger screen sizes, no one would click on it, and the event handler would not be triggered. At lower resolutions, it would be visible, and therefore clickable, and the event handler would already be attached. You might be thinking a bit too literally about the processes required for this functionality.

Comment: If needed, wrap your desktop HTML in a container that you hide in the same way as you show the mobile HTML.

Comment: I am using one div and trying to change it's contents based on screen size, so there isn't a second div to show/hide etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a solution after thinking about how to store the original html value.  I used `localStorage` to keep track of the original mark up on page load and then call it in the conditional after each page resize.

```
$(function() {
    var bcHTML = $('.breadcrumbs').html();
    var originalBreadcrumb = localStorage.setItem('ogBC', bcHTML);
    var getOriginalBreadcrumb = localStorage.getItem('ogBC');

    function breadcrumbAdjustment(){
        var screenWidth = $(window).width();
        
        if (screenWidth <= 600) {
            $('.breadcrumbs').html('<li class="sidebar-toggle">Good to Know</li>');
                
            $('.sidebar-toggle').on('click', function() {
                $('#sidebar').fadeToggle("fast");
                $('.sidebar-toggle').toggleClass('open');
            });
        }
        
        else {
            $('.breadcrumbs').html(getOriginalBreadcrumb);
        }
    };
    
    $(window).resize(breadcrumbAdjustment);
});
```

If you have any more elegant solutions, please post those as well.